# curl and bash script, doing a post request with a bearer token

Tags: bash, curl

Please educate me!

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

username="zDISABLEDc"
rand="Z01c20a936f474b"

single_quote="'"
curl_string_part1_="-X PUT https://api.secretkgbwebsite.com/api/v4.1/user/$username "
curl_string_part2_='-H "Authorization: bearer 00000000-4cd9-4bc6-90da-5d43a155f30e" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Postman-Token: 351e4bf1-04a2-4c99-8a21-21a05f51244a" -d '
curl_string_part3_='{"password": "'
curl_string_part4_='"}'

curl_string_complete="$curl_string_part1_$curl_string_part2_$single_quote$curl_string_part3_$rand$curl_string_part4_$single_quote"

echo $curl_string_complete
echo " "
success=0
curl $curl_string_complete && success=1

if ((success)); then
    echo "SUCCESS. password has been reset to : "
    echo $rand
else
    echo "problem sending and resetting password."
fi
```

The errors I get are:

> {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: bearer
>       curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 00000000-4cd9-4bc6-90da-5d43a155f30e"
>       curl: (6) Could not resolve host: no-cache"
>       curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
>       curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 351e4bf1-04a2-4c99-8a21-21a05f51244a"
>       curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 18

Now the annoying thing is that if I run the line that my program echoes out (this line: `echo $curl_string_complete`) with curl, curl is happy and runs the line without a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have issue with shell expansion process, see bash manual and posix shell manuals for more details. the syntactical quotes are processed before variable expansion so the quote inside variables are literal. In the case of echo the variables are split but because echo joins by space this couldn't be seen.

change `echo $curl_string_complete` by `printf "<%s>\n" $curl_string_complete` to see how arguments are split.

to solve the issue you may use arrays, something like :

```
curl_string_part1_=( -X PUT https://api.secretkgbwebsite.com/api/v4.1/user/$username )

curl_string_part2_=(-H "Authorization: bearer 00000000-4cd9-4bc6-90da-5d43a155f30e" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Postman-Token: 351e4bf1-04a2-4c99-8a21-21a05f51244a" -d )
curl_string_part3_='{"password": "'
curl_string_part4_='"}'

curl_string_complete=( "${curl_string_part1_[@]}" "${curl_string_part2_[@]}" "$curl_string_part3_$rand$curl_string_part4_" )

curl "${curl_string_complete[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It would appear `printf "<%s>\n"` will be a vital help in my bash programming future. Thank you for providing such a complete answer, it all helped in getting my script working.